# Creando una función para calcular la moda en R

Tags: r, funciones, programación-funcional

Como saben, `R` no cuenta con una función en el lenguaje base para calcular la moda (o valor más frecuente). Pensando en ello, me di a la tarea de crear una función muy rudimentaria que funciona correctamente y que comparto en este espacio con el objetivo de conocer cuáles serían sus observaciones, comentarios y mejoras.

De antemano muchas gracias.

El código:

```
#Base de prueba
numbers <- data.frame(var1=c(3,1,2,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,NA,NA), var2=c(NA,NA,2,1,1,4,4,2,2,2,2,1,1,5))

#La función
#Crea una data.frame con las frecuencias para cada número obtenidas con la función table
#Extrae el renglón donde se encuentra la observación más frecuente y crea una nueva BD
#La salida es el número más frecuente (la primera columna de la BD del paso anterior)

mode_calc <- function(x, ...) {
    freq_table <- data.frame(table(x))
    mode <- freq_table[freq_table$Freq== max(freq_table$Freq,...),]
    as.numeric(mode[,1])
    }

#Calculando la moda para las dos variables de la BD
sapply(numbers, function(x)mode_calc(x, na.rm=T))

#Salida
var1 var2 
1    2
```

Comment: Buenas Alejandro. Si el codigo funciona, no entiendo muy bien tu problema. Aqui no hacemos [codereview.se] ni opiniones y sugerencias. Si tienes un problema concreto como el de "funciona pero va muy lento" o necesitas optimizar algo, pulsa en editar para mejorar la pregunta con tu proposito concreto y los intentos realizados siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algunos comentarios sobre tu función, muy respetuosos y en plan constructivo y de aprendizaje comunitario.

1. Si tienes pensado usarla dentro de un programa (i.e. no vas a estar monitoreando el resultado, sino pasándolo a otra función que espera un tipo específico de datos) podría haber una inconsistencia, ya que tu función regresa un vector cuando todas las columnas de `numbers` son unimodales y una lista cuando son multimodales (ver `var3` del ejemplo). En realidad eso es un comportamiento (peligroso) de `sapply`. Te sugeriría usar directamente `lapply` en estos casos para asegurarte que **siempre** obtengas una lista como resultado. Las listas son más complicadas de manejar que los vectores, pero al menos ganas en consistencia.
2. No es necesario ni eficiente coercionar a data.frame, se puede trabajar directamente con tablas. No hice el benchmark, pero seguramente es más rápido evitando transformar los datos.
3. Los `...` no me parecen la mejor opción en este caso. Si lo que te interesa es pasar un argumento para el manejo de missing es mejor pasar ese y solo ese argumento y dejarlo **bien documentado** en la función. Por la documentación de `table` se pueden pasar `"no"`, `"ifany"` o `"always"`. Mejor manejar los `NA` directamente ahí.
4. No creo que sea buena idea el `as.numeric` de la línea 4,  ya que regresa el modo numérico aún cuando le pasamos un `factor`. Por ejemplo, en test de más abajo para `var5` regresa `1`, cuando lo razonable sería que regresara `a`. La moda se usa como medida de tendencia central principalmente para variables categóricas, en ese caso recibir la moda como un número sería un inesperado. En el caso en el que necesites los valores de la moda para hacer un cálculo posterior sería mejor hacer la coerción a numérico justo antes de ese cálculo y fuera de esta función, habiendo verificado que todas los elementos de la lista son numéricos y controlado el problema de las multimodales. Si el comportamiento esperado es que regrese siempre un valor numérico, incluyendo el modo numérico de un factor, eso debería estar muy explícitamente documentado en la función. No sería mala idea que emitiera un `warning` en ese caso. De todos modos creo que lo mejor sería que regresara un `character` y después no arreglamos para coercionarlo a `numeric` si hace falta.
5. Igual a 4, pero también para `character`. En el test de más abajo para `var6` regresa 12 porque `table` coerción internamente a `factor`.

## Alternativa

Voy a presentar un test data más complicado, con variables en las que `NA` es modal y con factores y caracteres.

```
numbers <- data.frame(var1 = c(3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA), 
                      var2 = c(NA, NA, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5), 
                      var3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8), 
                      var4 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                      var5 = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l","a", "a")), 
                      var6 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "z", 
                               "z", "z"), stringsAsFactors = F)


moda <- function(x, useNA = "no") {             #Para missing las opciones de table: "no", "ifany", "always". Deden ser strings.
  xtabla <- table(x, useNA = useNA)             #Para evitar computar tres veces la tabla
  names(xtabla[xtabla == max(xtabla)])          #Siempre regresa un vector numérico
}

lapply(numbers, moda, "ifany")
lapply(numbers, moda, "no")                      #Cambia el resultado en var4
```

Esta opción podría ser más consistente, ya que siempre regresa una lista de vectores de la clase `character`. De todos modos podría fallar en casos que no he pensado.

Comment: Gracias. Es justamente el tipo de comentarios y observaciones que estaba buscando. Y sí, pude constatar que mi función es super lentra tras hacer benchmark contra otra que encontré en la web. Supongo que el paso inicial de crear una data.frame hace la función bastante lenta. Muchas gracias por tu excelente respuesta. Saludos :)