# Valor que mas se repite en cada fila R

Tags: r, dataframe

Para dar claridad al problema tengo el siguiente conjunto de datos:

```
df<-data.frame(id=1:7,var1=c(1,2,5,6,4,NA,NA),var2=c(1,3,5,7,1,1,NA),var3=c(3,5,2,1,1,NA,NA),var4=c(3,5,2,2,NA,NA,NA),var5=c(2,5,2,3,NA,NA,NA))



df
   id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1   1    1    1    3    3    2
2   2    2    3    5    5    5
3   3    5    5    2    2    2
4   4    6    7    1    2    3
5   5    4    1    1   NA   NA
6   6   NA    1   NA   NA   NA
7  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Quiero generar una nueva columna, llamada `var6` con el valor que más se repite por fila (la moda por fila), en las filas `var1` a `var5`. Pero ahí no acaba, en caso de que no exista moda (como en la fila 1 del df), `var6` tomará valor 99. En conclusión busco que quede así:

```
df
  id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
1  1    1    1    3    3    2   99
2  2    2    3    5    5    5    5
3  3    5    5    2    2    2    2
4  4    6    7    1    2    3   99
5  5    4    1    1   NA   NA    1
6  6   NA    1   NA   NA   NA    1
7  7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Por cierto, agregué la columna id para destacar que tengo mas columnas en el df y no solo las que quiero comparar.

De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que buscas que regrese la moda cuando es unimodal, 99 cuando es multimodal y `NA` cuando toda la fila tiene `NA` (que no `99`).

El código que sigue lo hace. No es muy elegante, pero funciona. Es R base, así que no tiene dependencias.

```
# Calcula la moda y regresa una lista si es multimodal
moda <- function(x, useNA = "no") {
  xtabla <- table(x, useNA = useNA)             
  names(xtabla[xtabla == max(xtabla)])}

#Se aplica al data.frame por fila, regresa una lista
# No considero a id aquí, deberías ubicar un vector con los 
# índices de columna de las variables que quieres excluir
# en -c()
apply(df[ , -c(1)], 1, moda) -> maximos

#Si es multimodal le asigna "99", si no deja el valor de la moda
ifelse(sapply(maximos, length) > 1, "99", maximos) -> vector_modas

# Si todos eran NA en el data.frame la función moda regresa NULL, aquí lo pasamos a NA
vector_modas[sapply(vector_modas, is.null)] <- NA

#Ubicamos al vector como var6 del df
#El as.numeric podría estar sobrando
df$var6 <- as.numeric(unlist(vector_modas))

df

  id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
1  1    1    1    3    3    2   99
2  2    2    3    5    5    5    5
3  3    5    5    2    2    2    2
4  4    6    7    1    2    3   99
5  5    4    1    1   NA   NA    1
6  6   NA    1   NA   NA   NA    1
7  7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

> En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231587/creando-una-funci%C3%B3n-para-calcular-la-moda-en-r) pregunta puedes encontrar algunas comentarios sobre la moda y sobre qué se espera de la función `moda()`.

Comment: Gracias. En efecto hace lo que necesitaba. Como lo usaré en diferentes tablas modifiqué levemente el código para que fuera una función. Además probé también `apply(df[ , -c(1)], 1, moda) -> maximos` usando`apply(df[ , c(2:7)], 1, moda) -> maximos`. Sé que en el ejemplo que puse era más adecuada tu solución, sin embargo, en los datos reales tengo mas columnas a no incluir que a incluir. Estaré revisando la pregunta que mencionaste.